# How do I make sure GCloud is running node?

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have been trying to deploy a Node.js app on Gcloud run but it keeps coming up with the error: `The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=5000 environment variable`.

I was playing around with the port variable and `app.listen` but that all seemed like it was fine, it was listening on the correct port. Then I checked the logs to see if there was any more information and before the actual error, there was a warning: `bash: node: command not found` but I've specified `node: >=18.0.0` in the "engines" part of the `package.json` file and `nodejs18` in `app.yaml`. Is there something else I'm supposed to do that I can't find in the docs?

In the code I am using the following to serve the web page:

```js
this.app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

And here's my YAML file from GCloud:

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:
  namespace:
  selfLink: 
  resourceVersion: 
  generation: 14
  creationTimestamp: '2023-01-17T23:15:41.934438Z'
  labels:
    managed-by: gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
    gcb-trigger-id: 
    commit-sha: 
    gcb-build-id: 
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: europe-west1
  annotations:
    run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
    serving.knative.dev/creator:
    serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: 
    client.knative.dev/user-image:
    run.googleapis.com/client-version: 415.0.0
    run.googleapis.com/operation-id:
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: all
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name:
      labels:
        managed-by: gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
        gcb-trigger-id:
        commit-sha:
        gcb-build-id:
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
        client.knative.dev/user-image: 
        run.googleapis.com/client-version: 415.0.0
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '100'
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 300
      serviceAccountName:
      containers:
      - image: 
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
status:
  observedGeneration: 14
  conditions:
  - type: Ready
    status: 'False'
    reason: HealthCheckContainerError
    message: "Revision '' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The\
      \ user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided\
      \ by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain\
      \ more information.\n\nLogs URL: 
      \ \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    lastTransitionTime: '2023-01-26T12:36:36.279097Z'
  - type: ConfigurationsReady
    status: 'False'
    reason: HealthCheckContainerError
    message: "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined\
      \ provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might\
      \ contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: 
      \ \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    lastTransitionTime: '2023-01-26T12:36:36.279097Z'
  - type: RoutesReady
    status: 'False'
    reason: HealthCheckContainerError
    message: "Revision '' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The\
      \ user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided\
      \ by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain\
      \ more information.\n\nLogs URL: 
      \ \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    lastTransitionTime: '2023-01-26T12:36:36.208550Z'
  latestReadyRevisionName: 
  latestCreatedRevisionName: 
  traffic:
  - revisionName: 
    percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  url: 
  address:
    url:
```

Comment: Which gcloud product are you using? Do you get the error during the deploy or when you try to access the app after a successful deployment?

Comment: Can you share the code that you deployed?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your nodejs app does start on the port your container is exposing and running. I would suggest to use the default 8080 for troubleshooting.

```
# In Dockerfile

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

```
# in .env file

PORT=8080
```

```
// In nodejs (assuming expressjs framework)

//load the .env
require('dotenv').config();

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

```
# deploy command

gcloud run deploy <YOUR_SERVICE_NAME> \
    --image <YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE_URL> \
    --region <YOUR_PROJECT_REGION> \
    --allow-unauthenticated
```

Also, can you share the `app.yml` file? Looks like you docker base image does not include nodejs.

Comment: I have deployed this from the source code and don't have a Dockerfile, do I still need one? I have made sure that the correct port is open in the deployment settings and the code.

Comment: Dockerfile is not required. Do you have a basic image defined in the YML? Please share the YML file (or a part of it)...

Comment: I've included the YAML file that it's using, having removed a few things.

Comment: In your YML, 

containers: 
   - image:  

should reference a base image for your container... a nodejs docker image. 

Missing it, I presume your containers starts with some default image that does not include nodejs causing the message `node: command not found`

Comment: According to this docs https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service deploying without docker from source (as you do) does require node 12.... see the engine in package.json

Comment: I tried switching to node 12 in `package.json`, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash: node: command not found` error means that either the container you are using doesn't have NodeJS or the container you are using doesn't have a version of NodeJS that meets your criteria of version 18 or newer.

I'm not too familiar with Cloud Run specifically, but given that the error is coming from bash and not gcloud, my money is on the former, not the latter. I think you just plain don't have node on your machine, and I don't see anything on that yaml file that suggests otherwise to me.

Whether you use Docker or you customize your own vm image, you need to somehow get node on to your machine. (Your ports are fine.)

Comment: Yes, as previously discussed. I'm not using a docker image, I'm just deploying this from source code. It seems that using a docker image might be a better way to go though.

Comment: I didn't mean that you were explicitly using Docker, I was referring to the container in which GCloud Run runs your application. If you don't specify a Dockerfile, Cloud Run automatically builds a container by trying to derive what dependencies your code has. However, a container is involved in both cases regardless. It actually looks like you are configuring some of the container options in your yaml file (image, ports, resources, etc.) If you wanted to use Docker though, all you'd need to do is create a Dockerfile: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code